# Removing unwanted characters in the string using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a string like this in MYSQL table.

```
"Collectibles
 >
 Decorative Collectibles
 >
 Decorative Collectible Brands
 >
 Department 56
 >
 Ornaments
 [ Changecategory ]"
```

I need to convert this as ( that is separated with Comma)

```
Collectibles,Decorative Collectibles,Decorative Collectible Brands
,Department 56,Ornaments
```

I tried with replacing carriage return with comma, but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
'Collectibles
 >
 Decorative Collectibles
 >
 Decorative Collectible Brands
 >
 Department 56
 >
 Ornaments
 [ Changecategory ]', '[', 1),
'\n >\n',',') output;
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> REPLACE(
    -> SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    -> 'Collectibles
    '>  >
    '>  Decorative Collectibles
    '>  >
    '>  Decorative Collectible Brands
    '>  >
    '>  Department 56
    '>  >
    '>  Ornaments
    '>  [ Changecategory ]', '[', 1),
    -> '\n >\n',',') output;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| output                                                                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Collectibles, Decorative Collectibles, Decorative Collectible Brands, Department 56, Ornaments
  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```